# Load JSP files from external location

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I had developed a web project which will display a particular JSP depending on the user selection. The JSP files are in some external location, say `D:/folder1/`, and the project is deployed in Tomcat which is located in `C:/` drive. How can I dynamically load the JSP files into the web project?

Comment: What stops you from placing those JSPs in your webapp? Why exactly are they placed externally? Do you want to prevent *direct* access by entering JSP's full URL in browser address bar?

Answer (score 0):

The jsp's in your webapp will be converted to servlets and that will be used for displaying the content in the front end. So unless those external jsp's are available in your webapp, I don't think it is possible to load them dynamically.

You can use Ajax to load the jsp's and render their output based on the user selection.